# Javascript to change of a list items color when checked

Tags: javascript, html

```js
window.onchange  = function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list_id");
  var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("label");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      if (items[i].checked = true){
         items[i].style.color = "red";
       };
  };
}
```

```html
 <ul id="list_id" style="border: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); padding: 10px; max-height: 
     250px; display: block; width: 25%; overflow-y: auto;">
  
  <li class="member user_1">
    <label class="checkbox" for="user_1">
      <input name="user[1]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input id="user_1" name="user[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      One, User 
    </label>
  </li>

  <li class="member user_2">
    <label class="checkbox" for="user_440">
      <input name="user[2]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input id="user_2" name="user[2]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      Two, User
    </label>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I am trying to write Javascript so that when one of these list items is selected by the user, the color changes red just for the selected item. The issue I am running into is that this selects all of the list items, instead of the one that is selected.

Right now my Javascript looks like this:

```
window.onchange  = function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list_id");
  var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("label");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      if (items[i].checked = true){
         items[i].style.color = "red";
       };
    };
```

The HTML looks like this;

```
     <ul id="list_id" style="border: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); padding: 10px; max-height: 
     250px; display: block; width: 25%; overflow-y: auto;">
  
    <li class="member user_1">
      <label class="checkbox" for="user_1">
        <input name="user[1]" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input id="user_1" name="user[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
        One, User 
      </label>
    </li>
  
    <li class="member user_2">
      <label class="checkbox" for="user_440">
        <input name="user[2]" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input id="user_2" name="user[2]" type="checkbox" value="1">
        Two, User
      </label>
    </li>

   </ul>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When the code runs, no input is checked. Set one input element as 'checked'. Or add an eventListener to the input to trigger the function

Comment: The offending code is `items[i].checked = true`, change it to `items[i].checked === true` or even `items[i].checked`.

Comment: Except that `label` elements do not have a `checked` property, @A1rPun. The `input type="checkbox"` does though, and if the OP used the `for` attribute on the `label` correctly it could be used to directly go to the appropriate element.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I thought it was just a simple mistake, but yeah I know what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to achieve the desired result just what @HereticMonkey wrote in the comments.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('label')].forEach(label => {
  label.addEventListener('change', () => {
    label.style.color = label.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked ? "red" : "";
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      One, User 
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      Two, User
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also check out this cool [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1Lpbj8dz/) from @DavidsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: Thanks so much for the help here! Exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your JS by this, it will work:

```
let lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].onchange = function () {
    if (lis[i].style.color === "red") {
      lis[i].style.color = "black";
    } else {
      lis[i].style.color = "red";
    }
  };
}
```

Right now you are selecting all of your labels, and then setting checked to true (single equal sign), and then adding the color red to it.

I made it a bit simpler by selecting the li element, but there might be even more elegant ways to do it.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica True. My previous comment was not correctly formatted, I meant you can't really attach an onchange to all individual `<li>`'s because all the other `<li>`'s are not getting updated. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g0y43p67/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can add an eventlistener to the `onchange` event of each `<label>` element to `.toggle("class_name")`. When the child `<input type="checkbox">` element fires an `onchange` event, it will bubble up and trigger `<label>`'s eventlistener too.

```js
document.querySelector("#list_id")
        .querySelectorAll("label")
        .forEach(cb => cb.onchange = function(){
                                       this.classList.toggle("yoy");
                                     });
```

```css
.yoy { color: #de1e7e
     }
```

```html
<ul id="list_id" style="border: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); padding: 10px; max-height: 250px; display: block; width: 25%; overflow-y: auto;">
  <li class="member user_1">
    <label class="checkbox" for="user_1">
      <input name="user[1]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input id="user_1" name="user[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      One, User 
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="member user_2">
    <label class="checkbox" for="user_440">
      <input name="user[2]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input id="user_440" name="user[2]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      Two, User
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```